# Linux acls uses wrong gid for domain groups, but numerical gids ok

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, permissions, likewise-open

**Please see edit below**, as it turns out that the problem is with uid/gid to sid mapping and shows a workaround that will help understand the problem more quickly.

---

We have a Ubuntu 11.04 server machine (lets's call it data) joined to Windows Domain with tools provided by [likewise-open](http://www.beyondtrust.com/products/powerbroker-identity-services-open-edition/) 
So far so good, because i am able to:

1. Log on to machine with AD credentials
2. Set permissions for files and folders with extended ACLs and they work. So by setting "Domain Admins" permission on the folder, i can log onto machine with different domain admin account and access that folder.

So the computer itself understands which domain groups i am member of and can correctly handle permissions.

But the problem is when i want to access files from samba share. **Windows doesn't seem to understand that we are talking about same "Domain Admins" or any other domain user/group.**

### Details

The home folder has is acl-enabled

My share as it's in smb.conf:

```
[home]
        path = /home/local/MYDOMAIN
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = no
        read only = no
        writeable = yes
        valid users = MYDOMAIN\Administrator, @MYDOMAIN\"Domain Users", @MYDOMAIN\"Domain Admins"
        write list = @MYDOMAIN\"Domain Users", @MYDOMAIN\"Domain Admins"
        nt acl support = yes
        create mask = 700
        directory mask = 700
        hide dot files = yes
```

So far so good, i can access the share given that folder has read/execute permissions bits set for "others"

So lets try to access test_directory with domain permissions set. I remove any unix permissions:

```
janis.veinbergs@data:/home/local/MYDOMAIN$ whoami
janis.veinbergs
janis.veinbergs@data:/home/local/MYDOMAIN$ id janis.veinbergs
...1319633408(domain^admins)...
janis.veinbergs@data:/home/local/MYDOMAIN$ cd /home/local/MYDOMAIN
janis.veinbergs@data:/home/local/MYDOMAIN$ sudo chown root:root ./test_directory/
janis.veinbergs@data:/home/local/MYDOMAIN$ sudo chmod 700 ./test_directory/
```

So on the machine, if i try

```
ls ./test_directory/
```

Obviously, i get

```
ls: cannot open directory ./test_directory/: Permission denied
```

So i add all permissions for "Domain Admins". (I could have skipped the MYDOMAIN\ thing, because MYDOMAIN is the default domain for the machine)

```
$ sudo setfacl -m g:MYDOMAIN\\"Domain Admins":rwx ./test_directory/
```

I can do things in the directory

```
$ echo "yay" >> ./test_directory/test.txt
$ ls ./test_directory/
test.txt
```

So far so good, data understands domain groups.

But if i try to access that share on **windows machine** (from powershell):

```
PS> whoami
mydomain\janis.veinbergs
PS> gci \\data\home\test_directory
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path '\\data\home\test_directory' is denied.
```

Now, from data, i'll add permissions for others, so i can access that folder from windows:

```
$ sudo chmod o+rx ./test_directory/
```

Now, from windows, i can see files:

```
PS> gci \\data\home\test_directory


    Directory: \\data\home\test_directory


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                      
-----       2012.02.06.     14:56          4 test.txt
```

Now i can view permissions in properties window (localized, but you can get the idea)
[image: Permission properties]

I wonder why it shows Unix Group\domain^admins rather than MYDOMAIN\domain^admins ? What am i missing here and how to make it work?

### EDIT: Found a workaround

I'v found a workaround and possible cause but don't know how to resolve It turns out that some wrong mapping between id's are happening.

If i look up the sid-to-gid mapping with wbinfo for MYDOMAIN\Domain Admins group i find that the mapped unix gid is 10010. And this if i set permissions using gid, not the name, the permissions works and windows understands them:

```
$ sudo setfacl -m g:10010:rwx ./test_directory/
```

When i enumerate permissions in numerical form, to see gid's and sid's, i see that when settings permissions like MYDOMAIN\"Domain Admins", it actually uses a different GID

```
$ getfacl -n ./test_directory/
# file: test_directory/
# owner: 0
# group: 0
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:10010:rwx  <-- this is the actual GID mapping for MYDOMAIN\\"Domain Admins" group (setfacl -m g:10010:rwx) and it works when browsing share with windows
group:1319633408:rwx <-- this entry is when setting permission like setfacl -m g:MYDOMAIN\\"Domain Admins":rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

I then looked at my idmap configuration in smb.conf:

```
   idmap domains = ALL
   idmap config ALL:backend = lwicompat_v4
   idmap config ALL:default = yes
   idmap config ALL:readonly = yes
   idmap uid = 10000-33554431
   idmap gid = 10000-33554431
```

I see that the gid from ACL entry 1319633408 doesn't go into the defined scope. So i tried extending scope to 10000-3355443100, restarted smbd, but it still didn't work.

So now i have a workaround, to set permissions using gid's, sid's, but thats not user friendly.  What should i do to fix this?

Comment: Should this be migrated to ubuntu.stackexchange.com? Maybe will recieve more attention there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that i still had to install likewise-cifs support.

It was a matter of executing these commands:

```
$ /opt/likewise/bin/samba-interop-install --install
$ service smbd restart
$ service winbind restart
```

Credits to [Likewise Open 6 & Samba - A Better Open Source File Server](http://lordandhooks.com/blog/likewise-open-6-and-samba/)

Now when mapping SID-to-GID, i get back the correct GID likewise uses instead of the short one 10010:

```
sudo wbinfo -n "Domain Admins"
<i get long SID: S-...-512>
wbinfo -Y S-...-512
1319633408
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: <strike>Likewise</strike> *Centrify* doesn't like quotes around names with spaces. You should instead be using a backslash to note the group. So, when I am referencing my Windows group *Domain Admins* in Debian using Likewise Open, I would write `%Domain\ Admins`. Can you try that and see if it now properly assigns the GID?

## Update:

After a good night's sleep, I realize that I am not using Likewise Open, but their competitor Centrify Express. It's not a vote of one over the other, but a clarification for others who could be reading the answer in the future.

I have a spare machine that I can install Likewise Open on, I will use it to recreate your problem and create a new answer. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: That still doesn't work. When listing users with lw-enum-users tool or listing groups, they always show me that UID and GID is the long one... it's probably somwhere a samba misconfiguration... ?

Comment: Thank you for the effort, the issue has been solved. I'v provided an answer.